# Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type after Kotlin update to 1.6.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I was using [Android Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) library in my project to manipulate data from my SQLite database and everything was working fine in previous Kotlin version (1.5.31). Here is a sample of my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface ServersDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY connectedDevices, ping ASC LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getLeastLoadedServer(): Server

    @Query("SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY ping, connectedDevices ASC LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getNearestServer(): Server
}
```

After updating Kotlin to version 1.6.0, my code couldn't compile anymore, and I am receiving this error:

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
> (java.lang.Object).
> public abstract java.lang.Object getLeastLoadedServer(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

After some searching, I read that it was because of suspending functions, so I removed *suspend* keyword from my DAO, and I started getting the obvious error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main
> thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Even if I was calling those function from a IO coroutine.

I also read through the change log of Kotlin 1.6.0, that did not help much.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you use the M1 CPU? Kotlin 1.6.21 with Room 2.2.4 works fine for me, but I'm using x86. The same combination on my colleague's M1 doesn't work and throws these errors.

Comment: No I am x86. Check answer below.

Comment: I saw the answer but I don't understand why it works for me with Kotlin 1.6.21 and Room 2.2.4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Android Room ***2.4.0*** will solve the issue.

For Kotlin 1.7.10, you need to use Room ***2.5.0-alpha02*** or newer.

Comment: This saves my life. Thank you so much

Comment: doesnt work for me !!

Comment: @Malo Which version of kotlin you are using?

Comment: ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.0"

Comment: @Melo consider using older version of Android Room.