# Error with use of suspend on fragment kotlin room coroutine when upgrade jetbrain plugin 5.31 to 6.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-gradle-plugin

Using instruction suspend in room coroutine get a lot of errors like:

```
error: Not sure how to handle query method's return type (java.lang.Object). DELETE query methods must either return void or int (the number of deleted rows).
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteEvento(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()"
```

This happen when change  classpath `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31` to  classpath `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0` in build.gradle
What else may I do to use this new version of jetbrain

I put an example here: https://github.com/sysmart/ErrorSuspend

Comment: I am having the same problem. Had to revert back to 1.5.30. Did anyone found a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032625/not-sure-how-to-convert-a-cursor-to-this-methods-return-type-after-kotlin-updat Seems like this guy found the answer.